What movie has their character argue with a parrot at a drive thru?
There is a scene from one movie (probably from the 90's) that has left an impression on me and family. The male character pulls up at a drive thru and makes his order. The parrot, in the Italian dub we were watching, then responds: "E poi?" ("What else?")
The exchange then goes on roughly like this:

Character: No, that's all.
  Parrot: What else?
  Character: No, really, that's all.
  Parrot: What else?
  Character: Nothing.
  Parrot: What else?
  Character: I said, nothing!
  Parrot: What else?
(ad libitum)

None of the obvious search terms brings up anything on YouTube or Google, so I suppose we must be getting some detail wrong, or maybe it was just a really obscure movie?
Either way, your assistance is appreciated.

Is the parrot actually seen in that scene? Because there's an identical scene in Dude, Where's My Car? where Ashton Kutcher orders a meal at a drive through and the voice keeps asking "And then?", but it's not a parrot, just a Chinese stereotype that sounds like a parrot. Here it is:




...uh, so it wasn't a parrot? Okay...
